# Next.js - can't access cookies from getServerSideProps

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, next.js

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours but unfortunately, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have a Next.JS application with an external rest API (that I built using Express with an address different than the client). When the user logs in, I send a httpOnly cookie:

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.serialize("token", token, {
httpOnly: true,
secure: process.env.MODE_ENV !== "development",
maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 31,
sameSite: 'None',
path: '/',
}));

return res.status(200).send({
message: 'Logged in',
token,
email: result[0]['user_email']

});
```

The code above works - when I log in, I can see the cookie in 'Application' tab in Chrome.

Then in Next.JS I have a page component named index.js, and inside, there is this function:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    const token = context.req.cookies?.token || null; // I can't get this, even though I have it in app tab

const settings = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({})
};
```

Its main purpose is to get the cookie from the browser when I enter index.js, and then send it inside a POST request as authorization in order to get the values we want,
The thing is - I always get null from the token cookie, but I do see it in the Application Tab.

> My API address is: 'api.domain.com/api'

> My Client address is: 'client.domain.com'

Maybe it has something to do with the different subdomains or something because when I run both on localhost, everything works fine.

By the way, cors origin is: client.domain.com

What do I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: In the console log, what is `context.req.cookies.token`

Comment: I found the solution, please see answer below.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to document your solution.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there was nothing to document, I just added one line of code with the attribute domain (the name of the attribute says it all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was sending the cookie from server to client when signing in without the domain attribute, and as I said my API address is different (it is a subdomain but it is still different). That means that the cookie can't be accessed by the client side. I only had to change this in server side:

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.serialize("token", token, {
httpOnly: true,
secure: process.env.MODE_ENV !== "development",
maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 31,
sameSite: 'None',
path: '/',
}));
```

To this:

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.serialize("token", token, {
httpOnly: true,
secure: process.env.MODE_ENV !== "development",
maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 31,
sameSite: 'None',
domain: '.domain.com', // Added this line
path: '/',
}));
```

Without the line above (the domain attribute), the client's browser won't be able to send the cookie to our API. It is a good thing basically because it can help us secure the system.